# CodeKit: Sass/Compass Conflicts

Tags: compass-sass, codekit

I get this error when I try to compile using Compass on Codekit:

> Compass failed to run because your Mac has an older version of Sass
>   and/or Compass installed that conflicts with the newer versions in
>   CodeKit. You must remove all versions of Sass below 3.3.rc6 and all
>   versions of Compass below 1.0.alpha18. Do this at the command line by
>   running 'sudo gem uninstall sass' and 'sudo gem uninstall compass'.

I ran `sudo gem uninstall sass` and `sudo gem uninstall compass`, however when I try to compile through CodeKit again I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try running `gem query --local` this will list local gems, once you have a list, just go through and remove all sass+compass related gems with `sudo gem uninstall ___`, pretty sure that compass also has compass-core, but there are probably more

Answer (score 0):

How have you initially installed your gems? Is it possible that you've also installed gems with just `gem install`? Cuz `sudo gem` installs gems as `root` for all users while `gem install` only installs gems for your active user. So maybe gems left installed which aren't uninstalled with `sudo gem uninstall`?

On the other hand why uninstall compass at all. I am running Codekit 2.1 with its internal `Sass 3.3.10` along with the external gem `Compass 0.12.4`. That actually works quite well. You have go to `Codekit Preferences -> Other Tools -> Compass`and choose the radio button "Use the Compass executable at this path" and select your Compass gem then.

Comment: I originally used [this tutorial](http://guides.railsgirls.com/install/#setup-for-os-x) to install xcode, homebrew, and rbenv.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM for your ruby management then switch to your system ruby version

```
rvm use system
```

and install sass and compass for this version

```
sudo gem install sass

sudo gem install compass
```

This worked for me!